# Duplicate messages while logging in Python

Tags: python, logging

I think I've tried just about any combination and I keep hitting the wall with regards to logging. I've been trying to get my head around the Logging cookbook and various posts mentioning the same issue, but I just don4t get it. My code is fairly simple:

Main module (`main.py`):

```
#my modules
import manager
import metadata

import logging
import logging.config

if config_file:
    logging.config.fileConfig(config_file)
else:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Then in both modules (`manager.py` and `metadata.py`) that are imported in the `main.py` module:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

Finally, the logger config file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root, manager, metadata

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=console
qualname=root

[logger_manager]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console
qualname=manager

[logger_metadata]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console
qualname=metadata
```

If I now run the main.py, I will end up with only logging for `root`.

On the other hand, if I change my code as follows:

manager.py:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('manager')
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

metadata.py:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('metadata')
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

I'll get duplicate logging for `manager` and `metadata`.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, check the real value of **_*name*_** variable. As it depends on file location and import method, it can be not what you expect:

```
import logging
print __name__
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

For the second part:

From [Logging HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#loggers):

*Child loggers propagate messages up to the handlers associated with their ancestor loggers. Because of this, it is unnecessary to define and configure handlers for all the loggers an application uses. It is sufficient to configure handlers for a top-level logger and create child loggers as needed. (You can, however, turn off propagation by setting the propagate attribute of a logger to False.)*

So your config should looks like:

```
[loggers]
keys=root, manager, metadata

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=console
qualname=root

[logger_manager]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console
qualname=manager
propagate=0

[logger_metadata]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console
qualname=metadata
propagate=0
```

or like:

```
[loggers]
keys=root, manager, metadata

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=console
qualname=root

[logger_manager]
level=DEBUG
qualname=manager

[logger_metadata]
level=DEBUG
qualname=metadata
```

Comment: I added a different answer, but you're quite right; this answer allows you to keep the separation in loggers.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: Python logging: [different behavior between using fileconfig and programmatic config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819718/python-logging-different-behavior-between-using-fileconfig-and-programmatic-con?rq=1).

Basically, I had to add `disable_existing_loggers=False` to the `logging.config.fileConfig` call. Thus, the code that worked for me is:

```
if config_file:
    logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, disable_existing_loggers=False)
else:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

This also allowed me to simplify the logging configuration to just the root logger:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console
qualname=root
```